# How eliminate duplicate results in database

Tags: php, duplicates

Each time a user types a word into a text field, I call a function that writes the word to the database.

```
table:
id | word | category
```

Now if user paging the results, the operation repeats and the results duplicate in the database.

Is there a way to not duplicate the results?

Checking the word and category in the database will not give the expected result, because they can be entered today, yesterday, the day before yesterday.

Date and time also, because two users can enter the same words in a short space of time.

Comment: You can use Unique key constraint in the DB.

Comment: it's great to hear that there is a solution that is quite simple. But i must use this unique key to id, word or category?

Comment: Which one is supposed to be unique? Is the combination of all 3 of them unique?

Comment: Then create a single unique key or primary key on all 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dharman said in their comment, you can add a Unique key constraint. However, are you saying that the same word can be saved by different users and at different times? Or can the word only be saved once, no  matter what time, and no matter which user?

Also, just using the Unique key will work functionally, but what is the user experiencing? What do you want the user to experience? Do you want the user to receive a clear error message about what happened? If so, you will need to do validation which will require a query to check.

Comment: Problem is when user pagination result of what he wrote in the search engine. Then operation write in dtabase repeat and result duplicate in database when he paginate sults. I want only one time write to database what user wrote.

Comment: can be saved by different users and at different times, but not duplicate when user paginate results and operation saving is repeat

Comment: Ok, so I'm going to assume that the user is unaware what they are searching is being saved and we can ignore error messages/validation for now. I want to say that there is probably something that can be done on the front-end to prevent the behaviour you are experiencing, **but** if that can't be changed and to answer your question then you will need to have another field that you combine with the word to use together as a unique key. It needs to be unique to the user's current *visit* - I don't know what you have available, but if you have nothing you could create a guid perhaps?

Comment: I add new column in table and mix word witch unique key and check before run function and is OK. Thanks.